# PDO error: bound variables do not match

Tags: mysql, pdo

Getting these errors on lines 33 and 54 (my statement execute lines for the two queries), but not sure why. Looks like my bound variables all line up. Any thoughts?

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens... on line 33

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens... on line 54
```

Also, I have concerns as to whether this will work and the binding will accept the $SID2 variable with correct value, but can't tell until above errors are resolved:
    $SID = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    $SID2 = $SID;

Here is the relevant code:

```
$dbh = new pdo('mysql:host='.$hostName.';dbname='.$dataBaseName, $user, $pass);

if(isset($_POST ['submit'])){

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

$sql = "INSERT INTO stories(ID,
category,
genre,
rating,
story_name,
active) VALUES (
:ID, 
:genre, 
:rating, 
:story_name, 
:active)";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $_POST['category'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':genre', $_POST['genre'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':rating', $_POST['rating'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':story_name', $_POST['story_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':active', $a = 0, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                        
$stmt->execute();    //line 33---error line
$SID = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$SID2 = $SID;


$sql2 = "INSERT INTO writing(ID,
SID,
text,
position,
approved) VALUES (
:ID,
:SID,
:text,
:position,
:approved)";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);   
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':SID', $SID2, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $_POST['text'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':position', $b = 0, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':approved', $c = 0, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();  //line 54--error line
```

Comment: Hi Jaw, do you still need help with this

Answer (score 0):

In first sql is one value missing

```
VALUES (
:ID, 
:category,  ---> inserted
:genre, 
:rating, 
:story_name, 
:active)";
```

And the second one shuld be `stmt2` instead of stmt i think (also the bind`s)

Comment: good catch-that was part of it. The first query works fine and inserts all. But nothing happens with the second stmt2 query. No record is created. I think it might be because it is not getting the SID from $SID = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$SID2 = $SID;    but not sure...

Comment: @jaw any error messages? The "warnings" are gone? And you changed all `stmt` to `stmt2` in the second part?

Comment: Yes I changed stmt to stmt2 and there are no error messages at all. It's almost like the second query doesn't exist :(

Comment: Have you added `echo $arr = $sth->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
?> ` to find out if there any error message while executing the db statement?

Comment: I did now. Didn't tell me much. Returned this: PDO::errorInfo():
Array
(
[0] => 00000
[1] =>
[2] =>
)

Comment: Have you printed it with `print_r`?

Answer (score 0):

in your sql2 you bind to the wrong PDO object. You used $stmt->bindParam() instead of $stmt2->bindParam();

Just replact $stmt to $stmt2 in your $sql2 query.

Comment: Right you are. But nothing is being inserted into the writing table. The stories table is getting the inserts just fine...